# Vertical placement of textbox in R?

Tags: r, textbox

I can't change the vertical placement of my textbox for some reason. In the below code, inside the `textbox` function, the `c(-180,0)` portion specifies the (x,y) coordinates of the placement of the textbox. However, no matter what I make the y-coordinate, it is always placed at a y-level of 0. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am coding in R.

```
library("maps")
library("mapproj")
library("plotrix")
map("world")
map.axes()
map.grid(c(-180,180,-90,90),col=8,nx=7,ny=5,pretty=FALSE, labels=FALSE)
textbox(c(-180,0), 1, col=8, "lalalala", box=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textbox` takes arguments as `textbox(x,y)`.  The way you have it written you're passing `c(180,0)` to `x` and `1` to `y`.  I don't have the libraries installed, but try these three commands.

```
textbox(-180,0,col=8, "lalalala", box=FALSE)
textbox(-180,-45,col=8, "lalalala", box=FALSE)
textbox(-180,45,col=8, "lalalala", box=FALSE)
```

That should work